# Pass value from one function to another based on a condition in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to pass the provider id to delete function to delete the data sending the id directly to the function works fine but i need to enable another div to get confirmation like ok and cancel after clicking ok i need to delete it, but the function doesnot passing the values to enable it .

my delete function call is :

```
<td><Icon icon={editIcon} width="20px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<Icon icon={deleteIcon} onClick={() => this.onDeletedata(providerData.providerId)} width="20px"/></td>
```

I am sending the providerId as argument this onclick also enable another div which is confirmation div that is:

```
 <div id="modaldlt" style={{ display: (deleting ? 'block' : 'none') }}>
          <span className="font-weight-medium" id="name"> Are you Sure want to Delete ? </span>         
          <button onClick={() => this.setState({ deleting: !deleting })}  className="btn btn danger">Cancel</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.onConfirmDelete()} id="ok-btn" className="btn info">Ok</button>                  
        </div>
```

The providerId is only in the onDeleteData function i need to pass it to onConfirmDelete if the ok  button is Clicked

my funtion is:

```
onDeletedata = (providerid) => {
    this.setState({ deleting: !this.state.deleting })
    console.log(providerid)
    this.onConfirmDelete(providerid);  

  }
```

The providerId should pass to onConfirmDelete only if the OK button is clicked. plz sort out

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, do you mean something like this?                                  

`<button onClick={id => this.onConfirmDelete(id)} id="ok-btn" className="btn info">Ok</button>`

Comment: @LoXatoR not like that id is mapped to get data from api but the ok button is out of map

Comment: One way to do it is to extract the modal and make it another component, and pass the ID down as props

Comment: How can we know if ok button was clicked or not inside `onDeletedata` method?

Answer (score 1):

You can `useState` for your `providerid`

```
const [providerIDState, setProviderIDState] = useState(null);
```

and use `providerIDState` as parameter of your `onConfirmDelete` func

and you `setProviderIDState` in `onDeletedata` func

```
onDeletedata = (providerid) => {
this.setState({ deleting: !this.state.deleting })
console.log(providerid)
setProviderIDState(providerid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So onDeletedata is for opening the delete confirmation modal, and onConfirmDelete is actually you are deleting the data on clicking the  Ok button

```
onDeletedata = (providerid) => { 
        this.setState({ deleting: !this.state.deleting })
        console.log(providerid)
        this.onConfirmDelete(providerid); // 

      }
```

But  you are calling onConfirmDelete while clicking the icon for confirmation.

1. Remove onConfirmDelete from onDeletedata method.
2. Initialize a state that will update with the provider Id to be deleted
3. onConfirmDelete delete with the state provider id

else you can use the deleting state to store the provider id and check if deleting state doesn't have value that you have initialized earlier.

Something Like this

```
this.state = {deleting: 0} //initialize it to 0
onDeletedata = (providerid) => {
    this.setState({ deleting: providerid })
} 




<div id="modaldlt" style={{ display: (this.state.deleting ? 'block' : 'none') }}>
              <span className="font-weight-medium" id="name"> Are you Sure want to Delete ? </span>         
              <button onClick={() => this.setState({ deleting: 0 })}  className="btn btn danger">Cancel</button>
              <button onClick={() => this.onConfirmDelete()} id="ok-btn" className="btn info">Ok</button>                  
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a temp variable which store deleted values after onDeleteData. and don't call onConfirmDelete there.
2. Then on the onconfirmDelete store temp values to origin value. Otherwise empty the temp variable.